# Powershell Module function: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write my first Powershell module, but I have come across an issue I am not able to solve.

I have a logging function in the module which looks as follows:

```
function Write-Log {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [switch]$Success,
        [switch]$Error,
        [switch]$Path,
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$Message
    )

    $logToFile = $false

    if ($Path) {
    Write-Host "PATH SET"
        $logToFile = $true
        if (!$(Test-Path -Path $Path)) {
            Write-Host "Path not found"
        }
    }

    if ($Success) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green ("SUCCESS: $Message")
    }

    if ($Error) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ("ERROR: $Message")
    }

    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"].IsPresent) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow ("DEBUG: $Message")
    }
}
```

As one notices, the function is not complete. This does not influence the issue though.

When I call `Write-Log` from another script, I can run any combination of paramaters, except for `-Path`. As soon as I try and use `-Path`, I get the following error:

```
 Write-Log -Message "hi" -Success -Path c:\temp
    Write-Log : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'c:\temp'.
    At line:2 char:1
    + Write-Log -Message "hi" -Success -Path c:\temp
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Log], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Write-Log
```

Comment: `[switch]$Path` -> `[string]$Path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it written, Path is a switch parameter, not a string parameter. I think you meant to have `[string]$Path,` in your parameter list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either change the -Path parameter type to the type you are passing on the console in this case [String], and also on a different comment I think it would be better if instear of n number of switched you use a set to accept the type of log like this:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(
                Mandatory = $true,
                Position = 0)]
    [String]$Data,

    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateCount(0, 5)]
    [Array]$To = @($logRouteFile),

    [ValidateSet('Start', 'Section', 'Title', 'End', 'Information', 'Business_Error', 'Error')]
    [String]$Type = 'Information'
)
```

That's the parameters I use for my logging function.